# Identify computer via NAT in php

Tags: php, package, nat

Is it possible to read out the NAT-Header of an IP-Package to identify the sending machine in php.

My goal is to identify on how many computers my users are logging in to my page.

Best regards

Comment: assuming this is all on a local network (since we're talking about NAT), what's wrong with using cookies to identify them? or some other browser-oriented technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to do - there are numerous routers between you and final user.

The NAT is organized using NAT Tables which are stored in routers memory, so there is no sensible information in the network packages. So it's not possible *by definition*.

Comment: Yes you're right. But every machine puts a little bit of information into each package, so that all the numerous routers know to which machine my outgoing packages are dedicated to.

Comment: @JanP. The kernel takes care of that and not the webserver. The webserver get's only the data in the packets and not the frame headers

Comment: @Jan P.: I'm sure routers keep in memory all the necessary information and don't waste packages with something sensible

Comment: @Jan P: zerkms's answer is absolutely correct - there is no way to determine the origin of the IP datagram that passed a single NAT border unless the packet originator put some information into payload intentionally. The client's OS does not put any extra information but source IP address that is NAT'ed lately.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: NO!

The server gets only the last public ip of the request, in the case of NAT, the ip of the router.

Comment: "to read the original MAC address of the request" - from where?

Comment: @zerkms from the ethernet frame packet

Comment: why do you think "original MAC" is there? There is only MAC address of the latest router

Comment: @zerkms you are right, my mistake. i'll edit my answer. i always thought each packet holds the original MAC address as it goes through each network nodes. I guess NAT strips that